# Android Studio Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I'm developing a libgdx game. The code is compiling successfully, but after hitting run, the build failed, and showing error like this **Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'.**
Have anyone got solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've created your LibGDX project using `gdx-setup.jar` of latest [build](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/).

If yes try to update your gradle version to `4.6`

Check and update the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file in your project :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Refresh/sync your gradle project.