# Error : Internal Error, Could not execute build using Gradle distribution

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am using Android studio version 3.0,`buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'` What I am doing wrong exactly?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'


    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
}
```

> > Error:Internal error:
> >     org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-rc-1-all.zip'.
> >         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
> >         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
> >         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
> >         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
> >         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
> >         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> >         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> >         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
> >         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:77)
> >         .......

I have gone through,

[Android Studio Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949721/android-studio-could-not-execute-build-using-gradle-distribution-https-servic)

[org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-bin.zip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132700/org-gradle-tooling-buildexception-could-not-execute-build-using-gradle-distribu)

Comment: change gradle-wrapper.properties file inside `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

Comment: Can you show me the **Gradle console**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle error: could not execute build using gradle distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673636/gradle-error-could-not-execute-build-using-gradle-distribution)

Comment: `compile` is deprecated. Use `implementation` instead

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673636/gradle-error-could-not-execute-build-using-gradle-distribution/19845532

Comment: if `gradle-4.4-all.zip` not work use `gradle-4.9-rc-1-all.zip`

Comment: @Shaon I have gone through that link answers as well.

Comment: yep. Give them a try. Specially the 53 up vote answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put your gradle dependancies in new project. It seems Failed to apply plugin. Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the Android Gradle plugin since you are using Gradle version 4.6 or above.

Suggestion is file or use a Gradle version less than 4.6.

I just have replaced version of facebook sdk version to,

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'
```

**Gradle build successful**

Comment: Work like a champ, that solves my issue but, why is the version  `4.36.0` giving issue?

Answer (score 0):

in my case I got this error because of it couldn't delete some data (even after invalidates,restarts,rebuilds etc). I had have to delete the directory, pointed by the bottom of that long crash log, which started from gradle-4.9-rc-1-all.zip.

```
C:\Users\djdance\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\build\intermediates
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project Folder/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` , adjust 
*distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/**gradle-4.1-all.zip***
to whatever distribuation working from any other project.